# Cannot access statecode or statuscode of related Entity Via JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Hi All Experts ( I will be someday, soon ! )
Here is a question.
I wanna get statecode or statuscode of related Pricelevel ( Price List entity ) within the Quote Entity.( Related one )
I have tried JS this within Quote entity( OnLoad) :

```
    var priceLevelStatusCode=Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").getValue()[0].statuscode;
alert(priceLevelStatusCode );
```

But It displays me undefined in the alert box !
But when I try this :

```
    var priceLevelStatusCode=Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").getValue()[0].name;
alert(priceLevelStatusCode );
```

It gives me correct name of Price List within the quote.
What is the problem? How to get statecode or statuscode of Pricelist?

**Update 1 :**

I understood that should call `OData`, So I did this :

```
function autoAlarm() { 
    var pricelevelid = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").getValue()[0].id;
    oDataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/Organizationdata.svc"
    var Odata = oDataPath + "/PricelevelSet?$select=name,statecode&$filter=PricelevelId eq guid'" + pricelevelid + "'";
    try {
    var retrieveReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    retrieveReq.open("GET", Odata);
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    retrieveReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
    retrieveReqCallBack(this);
    }
    retrieveReq.send();
    }
    catch (err) {
    var text = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
    text += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
    text += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
    alert(text);
    }
    }


    function retrieveReqCallBack(retrieveEntityReq) {
    var PrefixText = ""
    if (retrieveEntityReq.readyState == 4) {
    retrieveEntityReq.onreadystatechange = null;
    alert(retrieveEntityReq.status);
    if (retrieveEntityReq.status == 200) {
    var retrievedEntity = JSON.parse(retrieveEntityReq.responseText).d;

    alert(retrievedEntity.hasOwnProperty("statuscode"));
    alert(retrievedEntity.statuscode);
    }
    }
    }
```

But now It gives me error 404 ( I think not found ! ).
Where I am doing wrong?

**Update 2 :**

I solved the error number 404.
It was because of case sensitivity. 
Now When I am gonna retrieve the value, It display me `Undefined`.

Here is my new Code :

```
    function autoAlarm() { 
var pricelevel = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").getValue()[0].id;
var pricelevelid = pricelevel.replace("{","").replace("}","");
oDataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"
var Odata = oDataPath + "/PriceLevelSet?$select=Name,StateCode&$filter=PriceLevelId eq guid'" + pricelevelid + "'";

    try {
    var retrieveReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    retrieveReq.open("GET", Odata);
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    retrieveReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
    retrieveReqCallBack(this);
    }
    retrieveReq.send();
    }
    catch (err) {
    var text = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
    text += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
    text += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
    alert(text);
    }
    }

    function retrieveReqCallBack(retrieveEntityReq) {
    var PrefixText = ""
    if (retrieveEntityReq.readyState == 4) {
    retrieveEntityReq.onreadystatechange = null;
    alert(retrieveEntityReq.status);
    if (retrieveEntityReq.status == 200) {
    var retrievedEntity = JSON.parse(retrieveEntityReq.responseText).d;
    alert(retrievedEntity.hasOwnProperty("StateCode"));
    alert(retrievedEntity.StateCode);
    }
    }
    }
```

It First display false( The code : `alert(retrievedEntity.hasOwnProperty("StatusCode"));`
and then displays `undefiend`.
When I go to the `Odata` URL in the browser here what I see about status and status code :

```
        <d:StateCode m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue">
      <d:Value m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:Value>
    </d:StateCode>
    <d:OrganizationId m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference">
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">f52acfb9-78de-402a-a9c2-8229836f0b7e</d:Id>
      <d:LogicalName>organization</d:LogicalName>
      <d:Name>xxxxx</d:Name>
    </d:OrganizationId>
    <d:StatusCode m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue">
      <d:Value m:type="Edm.Int32">100001</d:Value>
    </d:StatusCode>
```

Could Anybody help on this?

(SOLVED) Update 3 :

Finally I could get the `statecode`, Here is the code :

```
  function autoAlarm() { 
var pricelevel = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").getValue()[0].id;
var pricelevelid = pricelevel.replace("{","").replace("}","");
oDataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"
var Odata = oDataPath + "/PriceLevelSet?$select=Name,StateCode&$filter=PriceLevelId eq guid'" + pricelevelid + "'";

    try {
    var retrieveReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    retrieveReq.open("GET", Odata);
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    retrieveReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
    retrieveReqCallBack(this);
    }
    retrieveReq.send();
    }
    catch (err) {
    var text = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
    text += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
    text += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
    alert(text);
    }
    }

    function retrieveReqCallBack(retrieveEntityReq) {
    var PrefixText = ""
    if (retrieveEntityReq.readyState == 4) {
    retrieveEntityReq.onreadystatechange = null;

    if (retrieveEntityReq.status == 200) {
   var retrievedEntity = JSON.parse(retrieveEntityReq.responseText).d;
   var priceLevelStateCode=retrievedEntity.results[0].StateCode.Value;
   alert(priceLevelStateCode);
    }
  }
}
```

My mistake was getting `Json Array`, the true way is this :

```
   var priceLevelStateCode=retrievedEntity.results[0].StateCode.Value;
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pricelevel is a lookup in quote, you can get Id & name (display text) of that related entity record using `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").getValue()[0]`. For any other attributes (ex.statecode) you have to make a web api call to get it from Database using the Id key.

Update:
You can use 2011 compatible [CRM REST Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases/tag/1.5.0.0) to build queries, test & exact snippet can be utilized in CRM form js library. Download & import this managed solution in Dev CRM instance & right away build queries.

`OrganizationData.svc` can be used & retrieve the necessary attributes by wrapping in `XMLHttpRequest`. [Read more](https://deepakexploring.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/odata-and-jscript-in-crm-2011/)

Sample:

```
var pricelevelid = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").getValue()[0].id;

var Odata = oDataPath + "/PriceLevelSet?$select=name,statecode&$filter=PriceLevelId eq guid'" + pricelevelid + "'";
```

Comment: Hi there sir again, Thank you for your reply.
Do you have any sample of this? Any link?

Comment: @T_O can you confirm your crm version? You tagged both 2011 & 2013

Comment: My Version is Dynamic 2011 sir.

Comment: Hi sir, See my Update too.
It gives me now error 404.

Comment: @T_O this is not web api. This is OData. Have you downloaded Rest builder? Can you check all the schema names like entity name?

Comment: @T_O probably case sensitive entity set name issue. Check the changes in answer

Comment: I have updated the question.
Could you take a look?
Now it returns 200 on response, But undefined value of statecode.

Comment: Thank you sir,
I Update the question.
And put the answer there.
You solution helped !

Answer (score 0):

**Lookup** controls contain the `ID` and `Name` of the target entity.

In your case the Lookup control is the `pricelevelid` control

If you want more information from the related Price Level record, you'll need to to retrieve the specific record.

---

**To do this in CRM 365**

Here's the link to the [MSDN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrieverecord) on how to use this method, but basically you supply:

- Entity Name (in your case `pricelevel`)
- ID of the record (you can get this from your lookup control)
- Options (highly recommended to at least specify the columns you want to retrieve)
- A function to execute when the operation succeeds
- A function to execute if the operation fails

It should be something like this:

```
var pricelevelid = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").getValue()[0].id;
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord(
  "pricelevel", 
  pricelevelid, 
  "?$select=name,statuscode",
  function(record) { alert (record.name); },
  function(err) { alert(err); }
);
```